# Wordpress Site: PDF's are replicating virtual URL's

Tags: urls, pdf

- Single Wordpress Site
- Recently Migrated
- All software = Latest versions
- **Php 7.4.33** (previously had 8.1 but host recommended we revert to see if this may be a fix)
- Apache V 2.4.57
- MySQL V 10.6.14 MariaDB cll lve

I recently received a message from Google Search Console warning of a Canonical link error to fix… when I checked the console there were over 500 new pages all referencing the PDF files on my site. Each PDF is a static link and the code within the tab still reflects this or better said; the code has not changed.

The actual link is static and on-hover should look like this: “https://nanoplanetcbd.com/labtests/npcbd1010.pdf”

But now when I hover the link I get something like this: “https://nanoplanetcbd.com/labtests/npcbd1010.pdf?x45443”

Only PDF’s are affected. These PDF links are found only within the Product page Tab area “Certificate of Analysis” tab. The site is not replicating Products, Pages or Posts, just the PDF’s in the “labtests” directory and they are under constant replication. Each showing sequential numbers added after the “?x” Like this: “.pdf?x45443” “.pdf?x45444” “.pdf?x45445” “.pdf?x45446”. <—— this would represent just one file. So lets say 30 products each have 1 PDF associated within that Tab area and each has a unique set of virtual url’s & numbers being read by Google but they do NOT exist on the server, so this is not a physical copy, only virtual.

I checked my WordPress and server error logs and did not see anything that referenced the PDF’s at all. The ONLY reason I know these virtual URL’s exist is that Google sent me the Canonical Link Error email and when I check the URL’s I get to the PDF.

The tab(s) are located on each Product page. Here is a sample: https://nanoplanetcbd.com/product/full-spectrum-750mg-cbd-oil-tincture/

Here is the code used on the tab(s) I created:

```html
<p style="font-size: 0.8em;"><a href="https://share.confidentcannabis.com/samples/public/share/7383c396-7922-453a-81f2-0b4b82443448" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="size-full wp-image-11228 alignleft" src="https://nanoplanetcbd.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/badge-thirdpartytested.png" alt="third party tested cbd" width="100" height="90" /></a><strong>NOTE</strong>: *<em>Third Party COA Lab Results are Confirmed 100% true, no photoshop, no repeat edits on PDF's, no funny stuff possible when they exist on a site other than the sellers. </em></p>
<a href="https://share.confidentcannabis.com/samples/public/share/7383c396-7922-453a-81f2-0b4b82443448" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Click Here to see Confirmed Offsite 3rd Party Lab Results!</a>

<p style="text-align:center; margin-top: 20px;">Onsite Version<a href="/labtests/npcbd1003.pdf" alt="3rd party tested CBD" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="border:1px solid #000000;" class="size-full wp-image-11377 aligncenter" src="https://nanoplanetcbd.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cbd-certificate-of-analysis.jpg"></a></p>
```

Comment: My guess is that it's something to do with the `gdlr-` plugin (which I suspect is whatever `goodlayer` is.  Is that a theme, a plugin, I don't know.  It's appending something to the end of URLs, probably as a cache busting method. Do you have something set-up for caching or cache busting?  Or perhaps it's some sort of tracking parameter.  This isn't a server side issue so I think you can safely revert back to PHP 8.1.  Try disabling plugins one at a time and purging caches to see if that helps.